# Visual Studio Call Hierarchy, Call Sites, Location, Explained

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am debugging an application to comprehend the steps until an event of interest.

Didn't find an explanation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409859.aspx  (Call Hierarchy)

Who can explain what "Call Sites" and "Location" are intended for?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE** Based on the answer that it is character number.
[image]

My guesses are that:

```
Call Sites are the objects in memory calling the method.
Location has the ClassName | FileName - (LineNumber, ??)
```

What is the 9 for?

Comment: Character number on that line

Comment: From the looks of it, a call site is the method that calls your source method and the location is the exact location in the source code text.

Comment: @matt wilko Do you mean the amount of characters? Its not 9.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What do you mean by exact location? How to i interpret the 9?

Comment: `ReportPanels(0)` looks like it is two indents, so if tabs are 4 spaces, then The first letter of the variable starts at position 9

Comment: Ahhh from the beginning on the very left ... ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who can explain what "Call Sites" and "Location" are intended for?
>
> My guesses are that:
>
> Call Sites are the objects in memory calling the method.
>
> Location has the ClassName | FileName - (LineNumber, ??)
>
> What is the 9 for?

You're half correct. The "Call Sites" column are the lines in the source itself from where that specific function is being referenced.

The "Location" column is the actual file, line number and character position the specified call is referenced at.

So in the image you posted, the first line reads:

```
ReportPanels(0).Initialize(GlobalVariables.employee, expd) | ReportView.vb - (30,9)
```

This reads as:

A call to `Initialize` is being made by `ReportPanels(0)` in the file `ReportView.vb` on line `30` at character position `9` (white space in front is included in this count).

I hope that can help.

Comment: That is very helpful but one question left. My way of counting seems wrong: R(0)-e(1)-p(2)-o(3)-r(4)-t(5)-P(6)-a(7)-n(8)-e(9) ... How can a call be made from there?

Comment: ReportPanels(0) looks like it is two indents, so if tabs are 4 spaces, then The first letter of the variable starts at position 9 clearified it for me. Thank you all